# Nino Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have the following text, for example:

> nino&searchPhrase=jn123456&alphabetical

And I want to extract `jn123456`.

I've put together the following regex to extract NINOs:

`(\bnino?\b.*?|Nino?\b.*?)[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}`

The problem I have is at the very end of the regex where I'm matching the last alpha character which may or may not be there.

I've tried adding the following at the end of the regex shown above without any luck:

`?[a-zA-Z]{1}` and
`[?a-zA-Z]{1}`

Could someone please look at this and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: Please provide an example of the input text and your expected output.

Comment: What is a NINO?

Comment: Sorry @MarkusWeninger, National Insurance Number. Regards

Comment: Hi @AhmedAbdelhameed.

So here is an example of the input:

nino&searchPhrase=jn123456&alphabetical

and I'd like to extract please:

jn123456

Many thanks

Comment: @IRHM Check my answer below and let me know if that doesn't work for you. There might be better solutions depending on what regex flavor you're using. Kindly, provide that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
^[Nn]ino&?\w*=([a-z]{2}\d{6})
```

which will capture "jn123456" in the first capturing group.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7mwyuV/1)**.

If the character `&` can be anything else, then you may use `.` instead.

Comment: @IRHM Glad I was able to help :)